# How to get specific key counts that are serials

Tags: javascript

There is a dynamic object with the `item_description_` key suffix index.
In addition to these keys, there are other different keys.

```
const input = {
  ...
  item_description_1: "1"
  item_description_2: "2"
  item_description_3: "3"
  ...
}
```

How can I get the counts of the `item_description_` keys? Expected result should be 3 in the above example.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) See also [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131)

Comment: are there keys with different prefixes than `item_description_` and you only want to count the ones with `item_description_` prefix?

Comment: that's correct, there are other keys, and i only want the count of `item_description` prefix key counts @illusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all the keys of the object into the array; then filter on the key starting with `item_description` and count the length of the resultant array:

```js
const input = {
  another_key: 'x',
  item_description_1: "1",
  item_description_2: "2",
  item_description_3: "3",
  something_else: 4
}

const cnt = Object.keys(input)
  .filter(v => v.startsWith('item_description'))
  .length;

console.log(cnt);
```

If your browser doesn't support [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith), you can always use a regex e.g.

```
.filter(v => v.match(/^item_description/))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const keyPrefixToCount = 'item_description_';

const count = Object.keys(input).reduce((count, key) => {
  if (key.startsWith(keyPrefixToCount)) {
    count++
  }
  return count;
}, 0)

console.log(count) // 3 for your input
```

You probably should remove the prefix into a variable.

Edit: as per VLAZ comment, `startsWith` would be more accurate

Comment: @VLAZ true, thanks for spotting that. I guess startsWith or a regex would be better

Answer (score 0):

i think with regular expression will  also be a good choice, just two more lines:

```
const input = {
  item_descrip3: "22",
  item_description_1: "1",
  item_description_2: "2",
  item_description_3: "3",
  test22: "4"
}
const regex = /^item_description_[1-9][0-9]*$/
let result = Object.keys(input).filter(item => regex.test(item))
```